# How does session timeout work?

Tags: tls, openssl

I am using Ticket based session resumption. I need to set Lifetime of Session Ticket. So, that i am using OpenSSL API to set the timeout to session.

```
SSL_CTX_set_timeout(ctx,500);
```

after 500 seconds, established sessions will close the connection ?
or
After 500 seconds, session is not reused ?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [the documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SSL_CTX_set_timeout(3)) answers your question clearly. To cite:

> ... If the actual time is later than creation time plus timeout, **the session is not reused.**

Thus, it is only about reusing the session and does not have any impact on a currently running session.

Comment: Thanks for clearance @Steffen Ullrich. I have another question regarding to this only, Does it SSL_CTX_set_timeout useful to server side ? means whatever time is set by server, according to that time Server will decide whether session is resumed or not ? Right ? there is no meaning to use SSL_CTX_set_timeout at client side?

Comment: @DevangKubavat: session caching can both be used on the client and server side. But in the client you would have to explicitly pick the session so it is not on by default. See description of SSL_SESS_CACHE_CLIENT in [SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(3))

Comment: I used Session Ticket based session resumption in my application. so i disable the session cache. I want to give configuration to user can set time of session. after that time session will not re-used. My question is only server will decide the when session is expired. ?

Comment: @DevangKubavat: since the server is the one which accepts or not accepts a session resume at the end it only counts if the server still knows about the session or not. But since your are using session tickets and not session ids: all the needed information is contained in the ticket so no server side caching and thus no timeout of the cache is involved with tickets.

Comment: yes, but i want to set timeout SSL_CTX_set_timeout at server side... so whatever time i set using this, in ticket which generated by server, which has Ticket Lifetime Hint is equal to session timeout... that means till that time server will accept ticket after that, server will not accept ticket. So this timeout i want to configure...

Comment: @DevangKubavat: from a short look at the code I would suggest that SSL_CTX_set_timeout on the server side only affects the session cache which is used for session id but not for session tickets. It does not affect the timeout hint sent to the client in connection with a session ticket.

Comment: No, I already tested that, whatever i set the time using SSL_CTX_set_timeout on server side same timeout it will automatically set in timeout hint in ticket. and its work well. by default timeout hint is 300 second.